# How to end input when I just end inputting in on of 10 EditTexts i in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

There are 10 EditTexts.When I input these EditTexts, the softInputKeyboard shows "NEXT" and at the last EditText it shows "DONE".I can not hide softInputKeyboard until I finish inputting all of them.
However, I want to hide softInputKeyboard when I just end inputting one of these EditText.So  how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following in your activity's oncreate():

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code in OnCreate method.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Or if you need any other functionality with softkeyboard then use different option in place of SOFT_INPUT_ALWAYS_HIDDEN

I think this will work for you .Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

To close keyboard you should add this:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

To listen if text has entered you can add textWatcher. For example I use it to clear fields or set next focus after some symbols have been entered:

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,
                        int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
                        int i1, int i2) {
                    if (carNrEt_final.length() == 3) {
                        carNrEt11_final.requestFocus();
                    }
                    if (carNrEt_final.length() != 0) {
                        carNrGlobalEt_final.setText("");
                    }
                    if (carNrEt11_final.length() != 0) {
                        carNrGlobalEt_final.setText("");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                }
            };

            carNrEt_final.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Hope it helps